# How do I "short an audio jack signal to ground" when there is nothing plugged in?

Tags: amplifier, audio, short-circuit

In [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/258366/how-to-connect-jack-and-speaker-in-pcb), the answer states:

> J1: When the jack is disconnected it shorts the input to ground to silence it.

[image]

How does this work?

From the diagram, I'm assuming there is a signal and ground wire coming from `J1`. It looks like the signal and the ground are joined together and both flow to a signal ground (big triangle) and to a switch (small black triangle.) Presumably, the switch at the top is activated when the jack is plugged in.

I would like to emulate this setup as I have an audio barrel connector attached to an amplifier. When I disconnect the jack, there is a large amount of white noise amplified and I'm assuming I need to "short the input to the ground."

Here is the barrel connector i'm using

[image: 3.5mm barrel connector]

It's product code is PJ313D. Here is what I think is the wiring diagram for it.

[image: connector diagram]

Comment: What's an 'audio barrel connector'? Picture or part number please. The connector will either have the switch built in, or it won't. It's impractical to add one to a connector that doesn't have it, even if it's an option, you can buy switched or unswitched jack connectors for instance. It's even more difficult if it's not meant to ever have one, like a DIN connector for instance. You could emulate it with a physical switch to connect the input to ground, but you would have to remember to operate it when you unplugged your input.

Comment: I've added a picture of the barrel connector. Can you tell from this whether it is switched?

Comment: I've also added what I think is the circuit diagram for the product.

Comment: Terminology confusion: that's not a "Barrel Connector". A barrel connector is the type you'd typically find on small DC power supplies where the 'device' side is a circular opening with a pin in the middle, and the 'cable' side is a hollow cylinder (aka a "barrel") which fits both inside the circular opening and over the pin on the 'device side'.

Comment: You may be able to buy the switched version of your connector on the same footprint. It has enough terminals. Your particular model doesn't have the switch mechanics incorporated in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The circuit diagram you've shown for your connector doesn't include a switch. It's probably not practical for you to attach a switch to it. There are several options.

You may be able to find a footprint-compatible socket that does have a switch. If so, then you may be able to swap them over, and connect up the switched pins appropriately.

Depending on what aesthetics are involved, you could attach a switched socket somewhere else on the amplifier, and wire it to that socket. Or attach a separate 'noise off' switch somewhere, that you would have to remember to operate. If the latter, remember to tell somebody about it if you lend the amplifier to them.

You may be able to get close to what you want if the source that drives your amplifier has a low enough output impedance, for instance driving it from a line out or headphone socket. If you simply put a fixed resistor of maybe 1 kΩ across the amplifier terminals, this will reduce the noise significantly, and still be easily high enough for your source to drive. This will not work if the source has a high output impedance, or is something like a pickup where the load will affect the tone.

Answer (score 6):

When the plug is inserted, the tip pushes the middle upwards as it connects, thus disconnecting it from ground.

Like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

With your linked product, you don't.

It has no switch based on the circuit diagram you posted.

If you want to connect the audio pins to ground, you need either another type of connector, or if you want to simulate it, use a manual SPDT or DPDT switch to manually short the left and right audio terminals to ground terminal.